# global variable not getting set with proper values in another function in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a global variable 'csId' of string type. In the code below under drawChart() function, in for loop, csID variable should be set to '1' by the modelLocator when i=0 and csId  should be set to '2' by modelLocator when i=1.(considering lengh=2).
Alert in drawchart() (for csId) seems to be printing the right 'csid' values(both 1 and 2) but in the dataFunction() 'columnSeries_labelFunc' i am always getting the csId Alert value as '2' and never as '1'.

Please find the code below:

drawchart()  function::

```
public function drawChart():void
{
  var cs:ColumnSeries= new ColumnSeries();                                        

  var lenght:Number=AppModelLocator.getInstance().ctsModel.productSummary.getItemAt(0).collMgmtOfcList.length;
  myChart.series = [cs];
  var tempObj:Object;

  for(csLoop=0;csLoop<lenght;csLoop++)
  {
    cs = new ColumnSeries();
    this.csId= new String(String(AppModelLocator.getInstance().ctsModel.productSummary.getItemAt(0).collMgmtOfcList[csLoop]));

    Alert.show("csId="+this.csId);
    cs.id=this.csId;
    cs.displayName = 'Exposure';
    cs.dataFunction=columnSeries_labelFunc;
    myChart.series[csLoop] = cs;

  }
```

columnSeries_labelFunc() function::

```
  private function columnSeries_labelFunc(series:Series, item:Object, fieldName:String):Object  {
    var col:Number=0;
    Alert.show("value of csid in columnSeries_labelFunc="+this.csId);
    if(fieldName == "yValue" && series.id==csId){
        return(item.exposureUSDList[0]);
    }else if(fieldName == "yValue" && series.id==csId) {
        return(item.exposureUSDList[1]);       
    }else if(fieldName == "xValue"){
        return(item.rptType);
    }else
        return null;


  }
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: This happens because the code is run asynchronously that the csID value is already "2" when the alert is called in your columnSeries_labelFunc function.

Answer (score 2):

First: Assigning a value to a global variable repeatedly inside a loop is a bad idea. Nothing good will happen from that.

It's hard to tell from the context here, but the most likely reason that you're having this problem is that the flow of execution is as follows:

1. drawChart() executes synchronously, counting through each step in the loop, creating the ColumnSeries, which are each invalidated, meaning they will redraw on the next frame. The function ends, with csID at the last value it held.
2. The app goes into the next step in the [elastic racetrack](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/) and validates the invalidated components.
3. columnSeries_labelFunc is called, with csID still holding the terminal value from the loop.

The end result being that columnSeries_labelFunc isn't called until you're already completely finished in drawChart.

The simplest fix would be to read the id that you're setting on the series in the label function, rather than relying on a global variable at all.